# Visual studio output window shows To:0 From: 0

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, animation, visual-studio-2013

While running my WPF project I am getting following in visual studio.I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and this is the debug output that I'm concerned about: Is it a bug? Will it affect performance?

[image]